# Email segmentation with thousands of groups

Tags: civimail, groups

I am curious if there are any usability concerns with having thousands of regular mailing groups (not smart groups) to segment by county (3,142) in the US? Is there any guidelines or instances of Civi successfully running large scale numbers of groups?

Comment: if you mean Smart Groups i would def. make that clear in the Q

Comment: Revised, but yes, definitely not smart groups, that would be crippling.